# Issue with file system size

Tags: filesystems, size

I have problem with file system size mismatch from 2 different linux commands

```
du -h shows only 250 MB used 

df -h shows  9.5 GB used
```

Why is the different between commands ?

Comment: see [How to remember the difference between du and df?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41863/how-to-remember-the-difference-between-du-and-df)

Comment: `du -h` will show information on the directory from which you ran the command.  `df -h` will show information on full disk partitions.

Answer (score 2):

`du -h` only shows the amount used under the current directory, while `df -h` shows all the usage for the whole filesystem.